# Define a nested has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, activeadmin, rails-models

Let's suppose I have 3 models, `A`, `B` and `C` (where `A` has many `B`, and `B` has many `C`):

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end
```

So here everything works fine. With `A.first.bs` I get all the instances of `B` associated with the first instance of A, with `C.last.b` I get the instance of `B` associated with the last instance of `C`, etc.

**But want to be able to be able to do `A.first.cs` and `C.last.a`, how can I do this?**

**I want to do this because I want to be able to do `C.all.joins(:a)` because I want to graph some statistics about instances of `C`, grouped by `A`. Is there another way to do the same?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create [indirect associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) that traverse the tree.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :b
  has_one :a, through: :b
end
```

This will let you go from either end:

```
A.first.cs
C.last.a 
# etc
```

ActiveRecord will automatically join the intermediate model (B).